# R package to download CMIP6 data

Tags: r, download

I want to download CMIP6 data from [here](https://esgf.llnl.gov/nodes.html). Package 'epwshiftr' has a nice function 'init_cmip6_index' to index all the relevant information including the download URLs.

```
library("epwshiftr")

#this indexes all the information about the models
test = init_cmip6_index(activity = "CMIP",
                             variable = 'pr',
                             frequency = 'mon',
                             experiment = c("historical"),
                             source = NULL,
                             variant = NULL,replica = F,
                             latest = T,
                             limit = 10000L,data_node = NULL)

#to print the unique model
unique(test$source_id)
```

This gives me list of 18 models

[image]

There are many other models (for instance 'HAMMOZ-Consortium.MPI-ESM-1-2-HAM' and 'IPSL.IPSL-CM6A-LR') that have data as per my specification but I do not see them in query.
[image]

Is there a way to make this package work (or update the package) to include all the files which are available for download?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue trying to download MIROC6 data. I see it's available in ESGF but I can't get using this package. Did you ever manage to get it to work with other models?

Comment: Just found out that by default, `init_cmip6_index` looks for models with 100km resolution. MIROC6, on the other hand, has 250 km resolution. Thus it was not being retrieved.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. So how did you solve the issue? How are you retrieving the GCM which is 250 km. I am doing the same work and it will be really helpful

Comment: I think in the argument if you set resolution = NULL, it will download all the resolutions available

Comment: @89_Simple. You got it. I've set the resolution to NULL. However, recently I've been downloading CMIP6 data from the Copernicus system (https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/)